# At what temperature is the band gap value when obtained from Arrhenius plot?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, electronic-band-theory

Using the equation
$$\ln{R}=\ln{R_0} + \frac{E_G}{2k_B T}$$
we can obtain the band gap value $E_G$ by measuring a sample's resistance $R$ with changing temperature $T$ and using the parameters of the linear part of the Arrhenius plot. However $E_G$ is treated here as a constant, when in fact it is also dependent on the temperature. So the value obtained from this method would be the value of the band gap at what temperature?

Comment: Hey just an advice, you should maybe give one line introduction to explain about what you're talking about. It would be more understandable I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the linear part of the plot to extract $E_G$, then you are implicitly making the assumption that $E_G$ does not change much with temperature over the range you are considering (which is often a good approximation) in which case it does not matter at what temperature you are considering $E_G$; they are all about the same. If, in your case, $E_G$ is changing rapidly with temperature then you will need to use a ore sophisticated method to extract it and the question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the activation energy $E_a$ is at $T=0$, $E_a=E_G/2$.

I assume that we can linearize around $T=0$.

(I'm going to try check that)